# How can I add inputs to compositor nodes with Python?

Tags: python, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am writing a Python script that connects some nodes in the compositor. The result will render to  a multilayer exr, so I will need add some inputs to an File Output-node. I'm trying to use

```
node.inputs.new(type, name)
```

However, in Blender 3.4 I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Cannot add socket to built-in node
```

(Blender 3.3 simply crashes.)

How should I go about this instead?

Comment: Do you want to connect an input to existing sockets or are you attempting to add new sockets to store additional data (e.g. AOVs)?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here: https://developer.blender.org/T36706
Instead of:

```
node.inputs.new(type, name)
```

it should be:

```
node.file_slots.new(name)
```